# Conflicting types for function 'read'?

Tags: c

I keep getting an error that says "conflicting types for function 'read' ". My teacher wrote that function for our homework assignment, but it doesn't seem to be compiling correctly. Here's the declaration of the functions before main.

```
void flush();
void branching(char);
void read(); // The one that isn't working
void add(char*, char*, char*, char*, struct student*);
void display();
void save(char* fileName);
void load(char* fileName);
```

Here's the read function:

```
void read()
{
char student_firstName[100];
char student_lastName[100];
char student_grade[30];
char student_level[100];

printf("\nEnter the student's first name:\n");
fgets(student_firstName, sizeof(student_firstName), stdin);

printf("\nEnter the student's last name:\n");
fgets(student_lastName, sizeof(student_lastName), stdin);

printf("\nEnter the student's grade (A+,A,A-,...):\n");
fgets(student_grade, sizeof(student_grade), stdin);

printf("\nEnter the student's education level (f/so/j/s):\n");
fgets(student_level, sizeof(student_level), stdin);

// discard '\n' chars attached to input; NOTE: If you are using GCC, you may need to comment out these 4 lines
student_firstName[strlen(student_firstName) - 1] = '\0';
student_lastName[strlen(student_lastName) - 1] = '\0';
student_grade[strlen(student_grade) - 1] = '\0';
student_level[strlen(student_level) - 1] = '\0';

add(student_firstName, student_lastName, student_grade, student_level, list);
printf("\n"); // newline for formatting
}
```

It's also saying implicit declaration of function 'read' is invalid in C99.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: `read` is a predefined function in C . Try a different function name .

Comment: The "implicit declaration" thing implies that the code that's calling `read()` doesn't have access to either of your snippets.  We'll need to see more of your code.

Comment: What headers are you using?  There's a `read()` with a very different signature declared in `<unistd.h>`, so if you include that, you'll get the conflicting types error message.  However, if you don't include that, you should be OK — treading on thin ice, but you should get away with (but don't jump).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler <unistd.h> is not included in the program.

Comment: Listen to @ameyCU. Man page on a mac for read gives...
 The read() function call is expected to conform to ISO/IEC 9945-1:1990
(``POSIX.1'').  The readv() and pread() functions are expected to conform to
X/Open Portability Guide Issue 4, Version 2 (``XPG4.2'').

Comment: Is the `read()` function shown in the same file as `main()`?  If not, did you create a header with the various function declarations shown at the top of the question, and include it in both the file containing `main()` and the file containing `read()`?  Headers are the cross-checking glue that hold separate source files together.  They're used by the code implementing the function to ensure that the interface matches what was promised, and by the code using the function to ensure the correct interface is used.

Comment: Note that there is no prototype for `read()` shown.  You've declared a function `read()` that returns `void`, but the argument list is unspecified.  All we know is that it is not variadic (does not include ellipsis, `...`).  For a zero argument function, you need `void read(void);` as the declaration — only that is a prototype in C.  (The story in C++ is different.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes the read() function is in the same file as the main() function. All the other functions are working correctly except for that one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried changing it to void read(void), but I still get the same error.

Comment: Please create an MCVE ([MCVE]) for us and include it in the updated question.  It will have a declaration for `read()`; a definition of `main()` that calls `read()`, and a minimal function `read()`.  You'll show a minimal subset of the headers you're using.  And it will generate the error messages, which you will copy into the question.  Please identify the compiler you're using, and show the command line options used to run it.

Comment: `<unistd.h> is not included in the program` have you checked all headers that you include? and all headers that these headers include? and all headers that *these* headers include?

Comment: Change `read` to be `myread` and you are (basically) done.

Answer (score 2):

`read()` is a name used for [a function in the C standard library](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html); you cannot use that name for a function in your program. Pick a more specific name for your function, e.g. `readStudent()`.

Comment: Strictly, `read()` is not part of the standard C library; it is part of the POSIX extensions to the standard C library.  It is a name reserved by standard C for users.  However, if you work in a POSIX environment, you normally avoid using that name for a function you write — along with all the other POSIX functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler By "the C standard library" here, I mean the *practical* C standard library, e.g. libc/libSystem/msvcrt/etc. There will almost certainly be a function called `read()` defined there, and defining one in your program is likely to cause a conflict with the one in the standard library.